# Jqueryvalidation and Asp.net C# codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, validation

I am currently building a ASP.NET C# form. This form had many fields and many validations. 
Which included:

- Validate when the required checkbox is checked
- Validate a dynamic form (e.g. additional address form generate dynamically when add address button click)

At first, I was planning to use ASP.NET form control to create all the fields and validations. But later on I found there is a plugin call jqueryvalidation, which simply provided what I need through Jquery.

- Validate when the required checkbox is checked (http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/index.html)
- Dynamic form (http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/dynamic-totals.html)

and my question is, if I am going to use this, would it be easier for me to create the form using standard HTML form tag instead of .NET control? Or can I still use .NET control?

I am quite struggle as I want to use the .NET control because I can obtain the value easily in code behind instead of Request.Form["fieldName"] but on the other hand, I feel not convenience to use the validation that .NET provided and I am not sure whether .net can create a dynamic form as easy as Jquery either.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET validation will take care of both server side and client side validation, so use that.

Comment: how about create a dynamic form without postback like what it did here http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/dynamic-totals.html?

Answer (score 0):

with validation plugin you can use "when required" case like this

```
 $('#formSubmit').validate({ 
    rules: {
        ControlAspNetorSmtin: {
            required: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    if ($('#chkglobal').is(':checked')) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }


        }.... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC (which you probably should be) then your best bet would be to use auto-magic validation using model validation attributes and unobtrusive-validation. This would take care of client- and server-side validation with minimal effort (apart from defining the attributes).